# Excel Formula to remove everything from our URL after 2019

Tags: excel-formula

I've a list of URL for example

```
https://www.example.com/test/myurl/2019-11-20T10:09:25-05:00
```

What I want is to remove the 2019-11-20T10:09:25-05:00

I just need the URL on the left separated out BUT Please note the year, date and time is different on all URL for example

2019-11-19T13:48:46-05:00
2019-11-19T13:40:40-05:00
2019-11-19T13:38:56-05:00

The final result i need in EXCEL after formula is

```
https://www.example.com/test/myurl/
```

I am not sure how to achieve that - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try finding the index of the final occurrence of the path separator `/`, and then use `LEFT` to take the appropriate substring:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))),1))
```

Assuming that cell `A1` contains:

```
https://www.example.com/test/myurl/2019-11-20T10:09:25-05:00
```

then the output of the above formula would be:

```
https://www.example.com/test/myurl/
```